# "str" object is not callable

Tags: python, sqlite

```
def name_table_():
    global date
    global routing_number_open_date
    global number_of_parts
    global name_table
    global list_of_parts
    global list_of_cost
    global routing_number_number
    global routing_number_close_date
    global dstatus
    global milage_in
    global milage_out
    global service_advisor_tag_number
    global work_phone
    global home_phone
    global vehicle_identification_number
    global deivery_date
    global in_service_date
    global year
    global make
    global model
    global body
    global color
    global licence_number
    routing_number_open_date = input("R/O Open Date? ")
    routing_number_number = input("R/O Number? ")
    routing_number_close_date = input("R/O Close Date? ")
    dstatus = input("dstatus? ")
    milage_in = input("Mileage In? ")
    milage_out = input("Mileage Out? ")
    service_advisor_tag_number = input("Service Adviser/Tag Number? ")
    work_phone = input("Work Phone? ")
    home_phone = input("Home Phone? ")
    vehicle_identification_number= input("Vehicle Identification Number? ")
    deivery_date = input("Delivery Date? ")
    in_service_date =input("In Service Date? ")
    year = input("Year? ")
    make = input("Make? ")
    model =input("Model? ")
    body = input("Body? ")
    color= input("Color? ")
    licence_number = input("license Number? ")
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "("Name " + (str(d.month) + "/" + str(d.day) + "/" + str(d.year)), "routing_number_open_date,"
        "routing_number_number,"
        "routing_number_close_date,"
        "dstatus, "
        "milage_in,"
        "milage_out,"
        "service_advisor_tag_number,"
        "deivery_date,"
        "in_service_date,"
        "year,"
        "make,"
        "model,"
        "body,"
        "color,"
        "licence_number)"))
    conn.commit()


The full error is
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/cabca/.PyCharmCE2019.2/config/scratches/scratch.py", line 324, in <module>
    name_table_()
  File "C:/Users/cabca/.PyCharmCE2019.2/config/scratches/scratch.py", line 134, in name_table_
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "("Name " + (str(d.month) + "/" + str(d.day) + "/" + str(d.year)), "routing_number_open_date,"
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I've been trying to name a table dynamically, based of the date it is entered, and I just can't. I'm sure all it is a simple syntax error, or something that should be obvious, but the obvious is too hard for me to see, for some unknown reason.  I've gotten the error so many times, that i just can't understand what the problem is, I'm sure all I'm missing is some ""

Comment: Please add full error

Comment: You forgot a plus sign.

Comment: `"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "(` is indeed calling the string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this line:

```
c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "("Name " + (str(d.month) + "/" + str(d.day) + "/" + str(d.year)), "routing_number_open_date,"
```

Focus on this:

`"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "`

This is a string right?  and you are adding paranthesis after that line like this `"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "( .... )`.

I don't know  how `c.execute` takes parameters but if it takes one string, add `+` between strings. If it takes multiple parameters add `,`.

Comment: Yep, that was the problem. I only added the () so it would be one string, but it was trying to call it instead. Thanks!